# Why can't my Ubuntu Ansible ping my AWS machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I have `/etc/ansible/hosts` locally as:

```
[example]
172.31.20.nnn # nnn not shown, is 1-255
```

I created an AWS Ubuntu instance and a `.pem` file in my local directory I can log in OK:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-20-nnn:~$ whoami
ubuntu
ubuntu@ip-172-31-20-nnn:~$
```

However when I try

```
ansible example -m ping -u ubuntu
```

I get

```
172.31.20.nnn | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 172.31.20.nnn port 22: Connection timed out", 
    "unreachable": true
}
```

nnn is a number in all cases, just not shown here

I am stuck on adding ping - I see the following showing 22. What should I do ?

[image]

I see this, but I don't see ping in the dropdown. Should I be deleting the existing 22 rule that was already there? I tried that, without success.

[image]

Comment: where you have mentioned your private key? how did you ssh your machine? `ssh -i mypem.pem ubuntu@ip-address` or `ssh ubuntu@ip-address`

Comment: private key in local `.pem` file in the directory I am in

Comment: try this: `ansible example -m ping -u ubuntu --private-key=yourpem.pem`

Comment: That got the same error.  Feels like my .pem file might be wrong?  I've switched machine and thought it was updated but maybe not.  Maybe I should regenerate a new one.

Comment: yes, but must add the `--private-key=` parameter

Comment: I started again and got the same problem even though I'm using `--private-key=rubymd2` rubymd2 is the new `.pem` file

Comment: what's the version of ubuntu are you using and also ansible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your EC2 security group is blocking the ICMP requests. You just need to open the PING service on it

Comment: Select your EC2 in AWS Console (their online management), it will have `Security groups` in the left-hand column of the `Description` tab,  click on your Security group and then on the next page that loads click Inbound tab @MichaelDurrant

Comment: stull stuck. let me post where I am above

Comment: added another screenshot. ty